# What does SL represent in SLComposeViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6

I searched a number of sites to find out what does `SL` in `SLComposeViewController` represent or stand for? IMO, it represents Social Linking. But I couldn't confirm it anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just SOCIAL Compose View Controller. SL stands Social.

**Update:**
http://nshipster.com/namespacing/

Comment: Can you add a source?

Comment: You can see "Creating a Social Compose View Controller" in 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Any reference? `CA`,`UI`,`NS` etc. all these represent two distinct words. Is `SL` an exception?

Comment: Added one link in my answer, please look on. @Shishdem

Comment: @ArslanAli and `SCN` is the prefix for "Scene Kit". There is always exceptions to any rule.

Comment: @Ramdy online vaa da poriki

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the Social framework so SL is the abbreviation for SociaL.

Comment: Any reference? `CA`,`UI`,`NS` etc. all these represent two distinct words. Is `SL` an exception?

Answer (score 0):

How about "Social Layer" or "Social Library"?

From documentation,  SL* classes allow to do lots of things, such as:

"Create a network session.
Get the activity feed for a user.
Make a new post.
Set properties on a post, add attachments, etc.
Publish a post to an activity feed."